# How to split a collection into multiple subsets (with internal ordering) in Scala by predicate?

Tags: scala, collections

[I've checked multiple answers on Stackoverflow, all of those considered splitting to 2 collections, here, I'm asking about **multiple** collections with **in-subset editing**].

For example, I have 4 objects:

```
case class Data(id: Int, name: String)

val data1 = Data(1, "name 1")
val data2 = Data(2, "name 2")
val data3 = Data(7, "name 3") //note same name, different id
val data4 = Data(5, "name 3") //note same name, different id
val data5 = Data(8, "name 3") //note same name, different id

val data = List(data1, data2, data3, data4, data5)
```

What would be the most 'Scala way' to split `data` into, let's say, a collection of 3 Tuple by a **unique name** with **internal ordering in each subset** (for example, by `id` here)?

So in my example it will be:

`val res = List((data1),(data2),(data4, data3, data5))`?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thanks. I forgot to add an important part to it - editing it now. I want to have ordering in each of the tuples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do what you want combining some simple methods from the standard library.
The [**scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/) is your friend.

```
final case class Data(id: Int, name: String)

def groupSorted(data: List[Data]): List[List[Data]] =
  data
    .groupBy(_.name)
    .valuesIterator
    .map(_.sortBy(_.id))
    .toList
```

Which you can use like this:

```
val data1 = Data(1, "name 1")
val data2 = Data(2, "name 2")
val data3 = Data(7, "name 3") //note same name, different id
val data4 = Data(5, "name 3") //note same name, different id
val data5 = Data(8, "name 3") //note same name, different id

val data = List(data1, data2, data3, data4, data5)

val result = groupSorted(data)
// result: List[List[Data]] = List(
//   List(Data(2, "name 2")),
//   List(Data(5, "name 3"), Data(7, "name 3"), Data(8, "name 3")),
//   List(Data(1, "name 1"))
// )
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you want to sort between and within the groups.

You can do this like so:

```
data.groupBy(d => d.name) // Group by name
  .toSeq.sortBy(g => g._1) // Sort groups by name
  .map(g => g._2.sortBy(d => d.id)) // Sort group item by id
```

The result is a vector of lists, not of tuples, as each item in the list has a different length, therefore it can not be a list of tuples with the same structure.

If you want to limit/extend each group to exact 3 items, you can return a list of tuples i.e. (Data, Data, Data).